# Weird Footer Behavior

Tags: css, html, less, footer, sticky-footer

I'm relatively new to CSS, so please pardon me for the odd gaffe. I defined a footer to have absolute position, and it stays at the bottom for all all but one pages on my website.

...>The footer here behaves perfectly, i.e., it's position is glued to the bottom of the screen regardless of the content.
[image: Proper Footer]

...>Whereas, the footer below behaves abnormally, it's position isn't glued to the bottom of the page.
[image: Abnormal Footer]

I am using the same footer class on both the pages, so I'm not sure what's wrong here, mentioned below -

```
.shell3-Footer {
box-sizing: border-box;
padding: 0.9375rem;
border-top: 0.0625rem solid #dcdcdc;
overflow: hidden;
max-height:40px;
width:100%;
background-color:#f5f5f5;
position:absolute; }
```

Note that if I change the position to fixed, then the problem is only partially solved, as I need the footer to be seen only when we scroll to the bottom of the page. Also, when the `position:fixed` is used, I'm not able to view the down-arrow of the scroll bar - which is not *desired behavior*.

Additionally, there is a slight whitespace beneath the faulty footer which I corrected by adding `bottom:0px`to it.

Can someone help why the same footer class would behave differently on two pages? Thoughts?

Comment: If both pages have the same class, most likely it isn't because of the class that is causing a difference in behavior. Do you know of any other styles that might be added to the page that would make the two pages differ?

Comment: it would be easier if you show us the code, both css and html

Comment: Most likely its a problem with your html markup

Comment: I figured it out ultimately, the problem wasn't with the Footer style but with other classes on the faulty page. I don't wish to answer my own question as it was correctly pointed out by aug in above comment. How do I close this?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
body {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 100vh;
}

/* Put this class on everything that is not the footer */
.content {
  flex: 1 0 auto; 
}

.shell3-Footer {
  flex-shrink: 0; /* new stuff */
  width:100%;
  background-color:#f5f5f5;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 0.9375rem;
  border-top: 0.0625rem solid #dcdcdc;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```